# undefined local variable or method for Pod:Module

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, crashlytics, google-fabric

I tried to add Fabric pod to my local pod project. By adding

```
s.dependency “Fabric“
s.dependency “Crashlytics“
```

But when I did pod install it gave me this error:

> Invalid `myapp.podspec` file: undefined local variable or method
>   `“Fabric”' for Pod:Module.

Comment: which version of os are you targeting?

Comment: Here is the `podspec` of SwiftyDropbox just compare with your own and see what you're doing wrong https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/blob/master/SwiftyDropbox.podspec

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share your full Podfile?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove (`"`) and replace them with regular quotes (`'`).

Comment: It did not worked. Having single or double quote did not changed anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer, but it looks like your quotes are "smart quotes" instead. See how they are formatted differently from other quotes, that's probably your issue.

Your quotes:

```
s.dependency “Fabric“
s.dependency “Crashlytics“
```

Clean quotes:

```
s.dependency "Fabric"
s.dependency "Crashlytics"
```